# Alert in tradingView strategy get fired while it's not coming in list of trades section

Tags: tradingview-api, trading

I have strategy in trading view  which is running on 1min candle and I have configured alert for each Buy and Sell like following and sometime it fire the alert but not show in list of Trades . How it's possible ? is there any setting to control that ? my understanding was it should get fired only after it appears in list of trades.

[image: Trading View Alert]

[image]

```
//@version=5

strategy('ezz', overlay=true, pyramiding=1, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, calc_on_order_fills=false, slippage=0, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0)
strat_dir_input = input.string(title='Strategy Direction', defval='long', options=['long', 'short', 'all'])
strat_dir_value = strat_dir_input == 'long' ? strategy.direction.long : strat_dir_input == 'short' ? strategy.direction.short : strategy.direction.all
strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(strat_dir_value)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Testing Start dates
testStartYear = input(2016, 'Backtest Start Year')
testStartMonth = input(1, 'Backtest Start Month')
testStartDay = input(1, 'Backtest Start Day')
testPeriodStart = timestamp(testStartYear, testStartMonth, testStartDay, 0, 0)
//Stop date if you want to use a specific range of dates
testStopYear = input(2030, 'Backtest Stop Year')
testStopMonth = input(12, 'Backtest Stop Month')
testStopDay = input(30, 'Backtest Stop Day')
testPeriodStop = timestamp(testStopYear, testStopMonth, testStopDay, 0, 0)
atrRisk     = input.float(1.0, "ATR", 0.1, 10, 0.1)
atrLen      = input.int(14, "ATR Length", 1)
lvlDistance = input.int(1, "Distance", 1, inline="levels2")
lvlDecimals = input.int(2, "   Decimals", 1, 8, inline="levels2")
levels      = input.bool(false, "TP/SL Levels?  ", inline="levels")
decimals  = lvlDecimals == 1 ? "#.#" : lvlDecimals == 2 ? "#.##" : lvlDecimals == 3 ? "#.###" : lvlDecimals == 4 ? "#.####" : lvlDecimals == 5 ? "#.#####" : lvlDecimals == 6 ? "#.######" : lvlDecimals == 7 ? "#.#######" : "#.########"

testPeriod() =>
    time >= testPeriodStart and time <= testPeriodStop ? true : false
// Component Code Stop
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//INPUT
src = input(close, title='Source')
modeSwitch = input.string('Hma', title='Hull Variation', options=['Hma', 'Thma', 'Ehma'])
length = input(55, title='Length(180-200 for floating S/R , 55 for swing entry)')
switchColor = input(true, 'Color Hull according to trend?')
candleCol = input(false, title='Color candles based on Hull\'s Trend?')
visualSwitch = input(true, title='Show as a Band?')
thicknesSwitch = input(1, title='Line Thickness')
transpSwitch = input.int(40, title='Band Transparency', step=5)

//FUNCTIONS
//HMA
HMA(_src, _length) =>
    ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(_src, _length / 2) - ta.wma(_src, _length), math.round(math.sqrt(_length)))
//EHMA    
EHMA(_src, _length) =>
    ta.ema(2 * ta.ema(_src, _length / 2) - ta.ema(_src, _length), math.round(math.sqrt(_length)))
//THMA    
THMA(_src, _length) =>
    ta.wma(ta.wma(_src, _length / 3) * 3 - ta.wma(_src, _length / 2) - ta.wma(_src, _length), _length)

//SWITCH
Mode(modeSwitch, src, len) =>
    modeSwitch == 'Hma' ? HMA(src, len) : modeSwitch == 'Ehma' ? EHMA(src, len) : modeSwitch == 'Thma' ? THMA(src, len / 2) : na

//OUT
HULL = Mode(modeSwitch, src, length)
MHULL = HULL[0]
SHULL = HULL[2]

//COLOR
hullColor = switchColor ? HULL > HULL[2] ? #00ff00 : #ff0000 : #ff9800

//PLOT
///< Frame
Fi1 = plot(MHULL, title='MHULL', color=hullColor, linewidth=thicknesSwitch, transp=50)
Fi2 = plot(visualSwitch ? SHULL : na, title='SHULL', color=hullColor, linewidth=thicknesSwitch, transp=50)
///< Ending Filler
fill(Fi1, Fi2, title='Band Filler', color=hullColor, transp=transpSwitch)
///BARCOLOR
barcolor(color=candleCol ? switchColor ? hullColor : na : na)

//bar_index  = 4999
var buy_signal_1_alert_triggered = false

var stop_loss_price_L = float(na)
var stop_loss_price_H = float(na)
buy_signal = HULL[0] > HULL[2]
trigger = buy_signal ? 1 : 0
atrBand = ta.atr(atrLen) * 0.60
atrStop = trigger == 1 ? low - atrBand : high + atrBand
lastTrade(src) => ta.valuewhen(( HULL[0] > HULL[2] ) or (HULL[0]  < HULL[2]), src, 0)
tp1_y = (lastTrade(close)-lastTrade(atrStop))*1 + lastTrade(close)
tp1   = levels ? label.new(time, close, "1:1 TP " + str.tostring(tp1_y), xloc.bar_time, yloc.price, #00CC00, label.style_label_left, color.white, size.normal) : na


label.set_x(tp1, label.get_x(tp1) + math.round(ta.change(time) * lvlDistance))
label.set_y(tp1, tp1_y)
label.delete(tp1[1])
stop_y = lastTrade(atrStop)
stop  = levels ? label.new(time, close, "SL " + str.tostring(stop_y), xloc.bar_time, yloc.price, #CC0000, label.style_label_left, color.white, size.normal) : na
label.set_x(stop, label.get_x(stop) + math.round(ta.change(time) * lvlDistance))
label.set_y(stop, stop_y)
label.delete(stop[1])
sell_signal = HULL[0]  < HULL[2]

if buy_signal and not buy_signal[1] and not buy_signal_1_alert_triggered
    strategy.close("sell")
    strategy.entry('Buy', strategy.long)
    
    buy_signal_1_alert_triggered := true
else if sell_signal and not sell_signal[1] and  buy_signal_1_alert_triggered
    strategy.close("Buy")
    strategy.entry('sell', strategy.short)
    
    buy_signal_1_alert_triggered := false
 
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit('Stop Loss',from_entry='Buy', limit  = tp1_y[0])
    
    //strategy.exit('Stop Loss',from_entry='Buy', profit = 5 ,loss = 10)
    
if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit('Stop Loss',from_entry='sell', limit  = tp1_y[0])
    //strategy.exit('Stop Loss',from_entry='sell', profit = 5 ,loss = 5) 
   
plot(tp1_y, "atr", color.green)
```

Comment: Sounds like a repainting issue. Could you please share your code?

Comment: but if it's repainting issue then alert should not come as well . As per my understanding when trades comes in list of trade then only alert comes.

Comment: @vitruvius i have added code as well